# RestEasy - Parameters Binding - Validation and Errors - EJB

Tags: java, binding, error-handling, ejb, resteasy

Lets say I define a POJO with parameters that is passed to a REST call

```
 class MyVO {
    @NotNull
    @PathParam("name")
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @PathParam("age")
    private Integer age;
    // getters and setters
 }

 public class RESTclass {
   public postData( @Form MyVO vo ) {
   }
 }
```

It automatically binds the objects in MyVO. But where do I get the validation errors?
Does it trigger the validation during binding? If not, how to trigger the validations?

Spring does all these well. It has BindingResult parameter that you can inject. 
What is the equivalent here?

Any idea?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### RestEasy Versions Prior to 3.0.1.Final

For bean validation 1.0, Resteasy has a custom validation provider that uses hibernate's bean validator implementation under the covers.

In order to get validation up and running in Resteasy you need to do the following:

1. Add the `resteasy-hibernatevalidator-provider` dependency to your project.  Here is the maven pom entry if you are using maven:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
       <artifactId>resteasy-hibernatevalidator-provider</artifactId>
       <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Annotate your resource classes where you want validation to occur with the `@ValidateRequest` annotation.

   ```
   @Named 
   @Path("/users") 
   @ValidateRequest 
   public class UserResource extends BaseResource 
   {   
       @POST
       @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
       @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
       public Response createUser(@Valid User user)
       {
           //Do Something Here
       }
   }
   ```

   Resteasy will automatically detect the `HibernateValidatorAdapter` on the classpath and begin invoking bean validation.
3. Create an `ExceptionMapper<MethodConstraintViolationException>` implementation to handle the validation errors.

   Unlike in Spring where you have to check the BindingResult, when validation errors are encountered in Resteasy the hibernate validator will throw a `MethodConstraintViolationException`.  The `MethodConstraintViolationException` will contain all of the validation errors within it.

   ```
   @Provider
   public class MethodConstraintViolationExceptionMapper extends MyBaseExceptionMapper
           implements ExceptionMapper<MethodConstraintViolationException>
   {
       @Override
       public Response toResponse(MethodConstraintViolationException exception) 
       {
           //Do Something with the errors here and create a response.
       }
   }
   ```

### RestEasy Version 3.0.1.Final

The latest version of Resteasy is now supporting bean validation spec 1.1 and has changed the api and exceptions thrown.

1. Instead of the `resteasy-hibernatevalidator-provider` you are going
   to need the `resteasy-validator-provider-11` dependency.
2. You will not need to add `@ValidateRequest` to your resource classes
   as validation testing is turned on by default with
   `resteasy-validator-provider-11`.
3. Instead of throwing a `MethodConstraintViolationException` when
   violations are detected, an instance of `RESTEasyViolationException`
   will be thrown.

Documentation:  [3.0.1.Final Validation Documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.1.Final/userguide/html_single/#Validation)

Comment: Did you manage to make validation work with Resteasy 3.0.1? I can't seem to catch ResteasyViolationExceptions...

Comment: Take a look at your ExceptionMapper implementation and also how you are registering it.  Are you using classpath scanning, added it to your resteasy.providers in web.xml, or registered it via Spring?

Comment: As I can see resteasy-3.0.6 don't throw any exceptions: http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.6.Final/userguide/html_single/#d4e2429

Comment: Great answer, but when for path param age in url I specify some string like abc I do not get validation exception but  `org.jboss.resteasy.spi.BadRequestException: Unable to extract parameter from http request: javax.ws.rs.PathParam("age") value is 'abc' for private java.lang.Integer` which is not suitable for the client. Same issue is with Date. The validation should be performed before converting parameters to java objects, not after, as it seems to be the case. Any idea how to configure it that way?

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer!

Comment: @gregwhitaker can you provide me implementation of MyBaseExceptionMapper??