# Jersey method params validation isn't called in resteasy

Tags: validation, methods, jersey, resteasy, parameters

I created a custom validator for method parameters.

```
@Target({ METHOD, CONSTRUCTOR, ANNOTATION_TYPE })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = {OpsaTimeRangeValidator.class})
public @interface OpsaTimeRangeConstraint
{
    String message() default "Failed to validate to and from ranges";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

    //the index parameter in the method parameters for the from time
    int indexOfFromParameterInMethod();
    //the index parameter in the method parameters for the to time
    int indexOfToParameterInMethod();
}

@SupportedValidationTarget(ValidationTarget.PARAMETERS)
public class OpsaTimeRangeValidator implements ConstraintValidator<OpsaTimeRangeConstraint, Object[]
```

I have a rest service that is using resteasy, I am putting my annotation the rest method but the validation isn't called before the method is called.

What can be the problem ?

Comment: What version of Resteasy are you using?  Enabling validation differs between versions of Resteasy.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but I think you need to remove Jersey from the title and tags.  RestEasy and Jersey are different implementations of the JAX-RS specification.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to enable Validation: [Bean Validation 1.0](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.2.Final/userguide/html/Validation.html#d4e2419).

Add following annotation to the class to enable validation on complete class, or add it to a method for method validation.

```
@ValidateRequest
```

[This answer is more more precise (also for newer version)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17441202/3923366)